# How to recover repository using SVN hotcopy?

Tags: svn, repository, recovery

Okay.  I used svn's hotcopy to make incremental back-ups, now how do I test that the hotcopies will work properly?

I searched the posts here regarding hotcopy.  Most of them seem to just be encouraging the use of the svn hotcopy, but not talking about how to recover using hotcopy once made.

Is there any advice about how to recover using the hotcopy that I've made?

I also checked http://svnbook.red-bean.com/, but couldn't really find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this belongs on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Similar Question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444778/how-to-recover-from-svn-hotcopy-backups

Answer (score 19, accepted):

svnadmin hotcopy will always create full copies of your repository. It is not possible to do incremental backups with svnadmin hotcopy.

svnadmin hotcopy works like a filesystem copy command, except it will never copy open transactions.

To restore a repository you can just svn hotcopy your backup to the place from which you want to serve it.

For checking the integrity of a repository use **svnadmin verify**

eg:

assume your svn repos are on **/var/svn/repos** and your backups are stored on **/var/backups/svn** and your repository **my_project** is broken.

Use:

```
svnadmin hotcopy /var/svn/repos/my_project /var/backups/svn/
```

to create a new backup (do this every day or week..) and:

```
svnadmin hotcopy /var/backups/svn/my_project /var/svn/repos/
```

to restore your backup (note: you have to remove your repo before, as hotcopy will not overwrite your old repo, also you *really* should look for the cause of your repository failure).

Also use:

```
svnadmin verify /var/svn/repos/my_project
```

for checking the integrity of your repository

Comment: After you make a copy with svnadmin hotcopy, you can use svnsync to keep it up to date. Put a call to svnsync in the post-commit-hook and every commit will get backed up just after it is made.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for a smoke test? Just point any client at it (directly on the machine, with the file:// protocol if you want) and do some checkouts- the files constitute a valid repo. The hotcopy is just to make sure you get a consistent copy (eg, checkins that happen during the hotcopy don't screw up the backup).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternate to restoring a hotcopy if someone is looking for an answer. Install Visual SVN Server:-

1. On the left, right click on Repositories
2. Select import existing repository
3. On the dialogue box which opens, click on copy repository from another location
4. On the next dialogue box select your source repo which basically is your hotcopy
5. On the next dialogue box paste the location where you want your new repo.